# getting a persistent database connection for temporary tables in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a logger class that is being instantiated separately across multiple PHP pages.

The constructor does the following

```
    [
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    ];
```

So in theory, each instance of the logger class shares one the same, lone connection to the database. Each instance creates a temporary table, which should be created once (and erroring out in subsequent attempts, which it does). Each instance inserts records into the presumably the same temporary table.

But that's not the behavior I'm seeing. Sometimes, records that had been created recently (in the same PHP session) disappear. Sometimes, they reappear. Only the last record added is the only one reliably showing up.

It appears to be acting as if each time I create the logger class, I may get a new instance of the database connection or sometimes I get an old connection. It never reliably attaches to the initial connection. What could be causing this?

Comment: I made my PDO variable to the database a static property to further ensure I'm not getting novel connections to the database each time the class is created and even that makes no difference. The data in the table is still coming and going.

Comment: Did you solve that problem?